# Rails: ActiveAdmin sort by index, then by custom method value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, activeadmin

So, I have the following

```
Dialogue.rb
 belongs_to Chapter
 # Get the total number of dialogues in a chapter, then see what number we are
 def order_in_chapter
   chapter.dialogues.index(self) + 1
 end

Chapter.rb
 has_many Stories
```

Chapters also have an "order number" so we know what order to show the chapters in.

The problem is that on active admin, the business requirement is to sort by chapter, then dialogue number. Sorting by multiple indexes isn't too difficult, but sorting by an index and then sorting the returning association by the return value of a method *seems* impossible?

For reference:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Dialogue do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.includes :chapter, :character
    end
  end
  index do
    column :chapter, sortable: "chapters.order_num"
  end
```

This sorts the chapters correctly (chapter 1, then 2, then 3, etc.) but the dialogues within those chapters are returned in a jumbled order when I want for them to be returned by the dialogue.order_in_chapter method.

Is there a way to do this?

The pseudocode that I need is like:

```
StoryVoice.order(chapter: :asc).then_by(order_in_chapter: :asc)
```

Comment: you can't sort by ruby method result,  you can do it only via sql

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
column :chapter,
       sortable: lambda { Chapter.includes(:dialogue)
                                 .order('dialogue.order_in_chapter desc') }
```